# Converting CSV to fixed-width in Notepad++?

Tags: plugins, notepad++, text-editing, csv

Is there a way in [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++) to convert a comma-separated file to fixed width columns?

This feature exists in [UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) and explained in *[Working with CSV files](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/CSV_files.html)*, but I am happy with my Notepad++, and I don't want to pay for a copy of UltraEdit.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the built in TextFX menu.

TextFX -> TextFX Edit -> Line up multiple lines by (,)

I didn't discover this on my own, I found it [on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331754/topic/3958254) while trying to figure out this exact question!

Comment: Nice but "Out of memory" for 15k rows.

Comment: also it adds spaces to the file :-(

Comment: Radek if you want to split line, there is a feature just above in the menu called "split lines at..."

Comment: Note that as of Notepad++ v7, you have to install the TextFx Characters plugin using Plugin Manager.

Comment: TextFX doesn't seem to be available for NPP 64bit

Answer (score 10):

In the meantime I have just found a very nice tool for that. It's called **CSVed** and available [here](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/index.html), with many many nice features. If you hate Excel when viewing CSV files like I do, you should give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

For TSV files (tab separated) and newer Notepad++ release (either x86 or x64) the plugin [Elastic Tabs](https://github.com/dail8859/ElasticTabstops) is very helpful for this.
I have it configured for .tsv files and it works like a charm.

Another plugin that maybe helpful in conjunction is [CSV Lint](https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint), but didn't had the need for it yet. It features conversion between CSV comma, CSV semicolon and TSV formats.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible in Notepad: menu *Edit* -> *Replace...* -> *ReplaceAll* ',' by '\t'.

Comment: -1. Converting it into a TAB separated format does not make it  a fixed width column format.

Comment: Literally using "\t" does not work, neither in Notepad or Notepad++. It is always a challenge to use a TAB character in a dialog. A common work-around is to enter a TAB character in a document, put it into the clipboard by a cut (Ctrl + X) and pasting it into the field in the replace dialog.

Comment: OK, in Notepad++, selecting the option "Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x)" makes it work.

Comment: TextFX -> TextFX Edit -> "split lines at..."

Comment: @PeterMortensen It doesn't work unless your tab size is longer than (length of longest entry in column) - (length of shortest in column). E.g., if your tab size is 4, your longest line is 20, and your shortest line is 5. That, a very common use case, will still result in an uneven file.

Comment: @PeterMortensen But not in Notepad, as the user albs says.